# float vs unorm 0->1, which one is more precise?

Tags: c++, directx, floating-point

- Float - standard 32 bit IEEE float
- unorm - 32 bit (range 0->1)

Which one is more precise **when used to represent data in the 0->1 range**? Or are there no precision differences?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A float represents values outside of the [0,1] range as well (only about 1/4 of floating point numbers lie in that range).  So there are ~2^30 floats in that interval, but 2^32 unorms.

Floats deliver more precision close to zero, but averaged over the whole range, unorms are more precise.  (The resolution of floats over that range varies from 2^-149 to 2^-24; unorms have constant spacing of 2^-32).